# proof that if $A$ is open in $(X,d_X)$ then the subset $G $ of $A$ is open in $(A, d_A)$ if and only if it is open in $(X, d_X)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $A$ be a subset of $X$. We shall consider $A$ with the subset metric $(A, d_A)$.

We will show that if $A$ is open in $(X,d_X)$ then the subset $G$ of $A$ is open in $(A, d_A)$ if and only if it is open in $(X, d_X)$

$\Leftarrow$ Let $G \subseteq A$ and let $G$ be open in $(X, d)$. This implies that there exist an $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $B_X (x, \epsilon) \subseteq G$ for all $x \in G$. Since we have that $d_A(x,y) =d(x,y) $ $ \forall x,y \in A$ it implies that $B_A(x,\epsilon) = B_X(x,\epsilon) \subseteq G \subseteq A \subseteq X$ and thus G is also open in $(A, d_A)$

$\Rightarrow$ Let $A$ be open in $(X,d_X)$ and $G \subseteq A$ be open in $(A, d_A)$ we have to show that $G$ is also open in $(X, d_X)$. Since $A$ be open in $(X,d_X)$ we now that there exist an $\epsilon_1>0$ s.t. $B_X (x, \epsilon_1) \subseteq A$ for all $x \in A$. Since $G$ be open in $(A,d_A)$ we now that there exist an $\epsilon_2>0$ s.t. $B_A (x, \epsilon_2) \subseteq G$ for all $x \in G$. If we simply set $\epsilon = min(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ (Do I really need to do this? Would it not be sufficient to set $\epsilon = \epsilon_2$ since $G \subseteq A \subseteq X$? This at least my intuition thinking about it in $R^2$) we have that $B_X (x, \epsilon) \subseteq G$
for all $x\in G$. Hence, $ G$ is open in $(X,d_X)$.

Let me know what you guys think, I'm a bit confused why it should be more complicated than this? Pls answer my question in parenthesis in the proof. Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand why I need $min(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$ after looking at the definition for open balls. I thought too much about A as a subset rather than a metric space...easy to get confused hahah

Comment: In fact the statement holds without the assumption of the existence of a metric.

Answer (score 1):

The key observation is that a ball in $A$ could be represented as $B_A(x, r)=A\cap B_X(x, r)$. This can imply that any open set in $A$ could be represented as $A\cap U$, where $U$ is open in $X$.